# Degree bounds on coordinates of points in a zero-dimensional variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, computer-algebra

Let $S = \{f_1, \dots, f_s \in \mathbb{Q}[x_1, \dots, x_n]\}$ have a zero-dimensional nullset $V \subset \mathbb{C}^n$, and suppose that each $f_i$ has total degree at most $d$.

Is there a shared root $(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n) \in V$ such that some $\alpha_i$ has degree at most $dn$ as an algebraic integer (i.e. such that $[\mathbb{Q}[\alpha_i] : \mathbb{Q}] \leq dn$)?

This is vaguely  along the lines of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1801655/bounding-the-degree-of-an-algebraic-extension-containing-solutions-to-polynomial) question but asking about the "minimal" coordinate rather than the degree of the extension needed to contain all the coordinates. I know there's a bound of $d^n$ (from the link, or via Bezout's Inequality followed by the Shape Lemma) but I'm wondering if more can be said after trying some examples and not finding anything worse than $dn$.

Comment: Take a simple example with maximal degree $d^n$ (for example, $x_1^d=2$ and $x_{i+1}^d=x_i$, $i=1,\dots,n-1$). Then make the change of coordinates $x_i'=x_i+x_n$, $i=1,\dots,n-1$.

Comment: I see - would it make more sense to ask if there was a shared root and an appropriate coordinate system such that there was a root with a low-degree coordinate?